# Flutter how to create list of images

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create the list of images as shown in the images below, how can I do it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Stack` widget with `Positioned` widget to create a "stack" style of images.

To bring an image to the foreground, you'll have to modify the order of your children's stack and rebuild the widget with `SetState`